# jQuery Slider Bar to Select Two dependent values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need some help on making a slider bar or scale in jquery. There are two values which are to be determined by the slider. The amount of sweet and salt. Their will be one button on the slider to slide. When the slider on 30% the other value should be 70%. i.e the sum should always make 100%.

how could i make such a slider? I have looked at jQuery Slider plugin but it does not have such an option. I have also Googled it but could not find an example of such a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI slider can be used to do this

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
Sweet:<div id="sweet">0</div>
Salt:<div id="salt">100</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $('#sweet').text(ui.value);
            $('#salt').text(100 - ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hP7mT/)

Comment: how would I be able to use this to input the two values into a database? With the range input you can only input one value and it doesn't have an option to input a second value, this is the only option. A little confused on how to use it with php/mysql

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general method to do something like this (will create an example if needed):

1. Create two sliders.
2. In jQuery, subscribe to the "changed" event of both sliders.
3. if one slider changes, set the value of the other slider to `100-thisSliderPercent`.

Thus, if one is dragged, the other responds.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3TfLP/7/) is a jsFiddle with an example.**

```
$("#slider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider2").slider("value", 100 - ui.value);
    }
});
$("#slider2").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider1").slider("value", 100 - ui.value);
    }
});
```

`<div id="slider1"></div><br/><div id="slider2"></div>`